# Pandas DataFrame manipulation with Date as index

Tags: python, pandas

I deal with DataFrame where indexes are dates:

```
Date        Status 1   
2015-01-01  1    
2015-02-01  2    
2015-03-01  2    
2015-04-01  3    
2015-05-01  5
```

I want to compare this DataFrame with a second one that is missing some rows:

```
Date        Status 2    
2015-02-01  2    
2015-03-01  3    
2015-04-01  2    
2015-05-01  6
```

You can see that on 2015-01-01, I have no data

I want to fill in missing dates with 0s

Can anyone help me with an easy way?

Thanks

PS: Sorry for this post formatting... but I couldn't render nice rows and columns render like on my Spyder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2.reindex(df1.index,fill_value=0)

            Status 2
Date                
2015-01-01         0
2015-02-01         2
2015-03-01         3
2015-04-01         2
2015-05-01         6
```

Comment: Join or merge to directly compare?

Comment: Thanks sacul... just implemented!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.merge(df1,how='left', on='Date') #you can use 'outer' in how, if empty Date is in both sets
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: typo `inplae` :)